# Display a Column in a RIght Order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Goal:
To retrieve the order in a right order.

```
Requested result in the table

a = nvarchar
n = int
text = nvarchar


a  n  text
----------
a  3  sd  
a  2  df
a  1  cv
c  2  we
c  1  qw
b  5  zx
b  4  hj
b  3  cv
b  2  fv
b  1  av
...
...
...
...
...
...
more rows to go
```

Problem:
I don't know how to do it with SQL code in order to retrieve the column 'n' in a right order. The right order is displayed in the goal part.

```
a = nvarchar
n = int
text = nvarchar


a  n  text
----------
a  1  sd  
a  2  df
a  3  cv
c  1  we
c  2  qw
b  1  zx
b  2  hj
b  3  cv
b  4  fv
b  5  av
...
...
...
...
...
...
more rows to go
```

Comment: Where is the desired order, in the first or in the second result-set? The first is the one with the "goal" above. Btw, did you try anything?

Comment: desired order is in the goal part or first result set. Please inform if you need more explanation

Comment: So why is the descending oredered `c-group` before the `b-group`?

Comment: The column for a and text is static and cannot be changed. It need to be kept as it is in the desired and current table. The only column shall be changed is column 'n'

Comment: That means you want to know how to **update** your table to take the new `n` column ordering into account?

Comment: Tim: Yes, it's correct. Changing only the column 'n' and its chronological order for the data. The desired value start with the highest value and goes down all the way to value '1'. It can be changed or you also can add a new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I: So you want to know how to update your table to take the new n column ordering into account?

You: Yes, it's correct. Changing only the column `n`  and its chronological order for the data. The desired value start with the highest value and goes down all the way to value '1'. It can be changed or you also can add a new column.

You can  update the `n`-column  with `ROW_NUMBER` in a `CTE`:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT a, n, text, 
           rn = Row_number() 
                 OVER( 
                   partition BY a 
                   ORDER BY n DESC) 
    FROM   dbo.Table1) 
UPDATE cte 
SET    n = rn;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4bcb5/10/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify order like that:

```
SELECT
    a, n, txt
FROM
    TableName
ORDER BY
    a,
    n DESC
```

But it will sort according to `a` value first too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table order by a, n
```

Comment: what is the 'instruction'?

Comment: wait, so column n is a dynamic column which you wanted to build with the number your want? or it is a real column and you want to change the value inside it? better to make it clear in your question, it is so not clear, and confusing. I guess @Tim Schmelter's code will work